# Disable little arrows on far end of line

Tags: emacs

On Emacs (GTK) if I have a slit window that is not able to show an entire line, it will show some little arrows indicating there is more text to the right.

How can I disable those little arrows?

(screenshot of the little arrows I want to remove https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8DVT.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See "[Fringes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fringes.html)" in the Emacs manual, or type <kbd>M-x set-fringe-style RET no-fringes RET</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to adjust the value of the variable `fringe-indicator-alist`. Take a look at its default value with <kbd>C-h v fringe-indicator-alist</kbd> and remove the indicators that you don't want to see.

Another simpler solution would be to turn-off `visual-line-mode` (which causes the triangles to be displayed). Adding this to your init file should do the trick:

```
(visual-line-mode -1)
```